# C for loop goes on forever and I think I wrote the program wrong

Tags: c

This is my homework assignment:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    char v[2] = {'A', 'I'};
    char c[3] = {'n', 's', 't'};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < c[i]; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", c[6]);

        for (i = 0; i < v[i]; i++) {
            printf("%d %d", v[2]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to go on forever and I don't know what to do. Keep in mind that I am new to C, so I tried my best.

Comment: `printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", c[6]);` is wrong on multiple levels. What do you intend to do here?

Comment: The comparison between `i` (0,1,2...) and `c[i]` ('n', 's', 't') makes no sense in `for (i = 0; i < c[i]; i++)` When did you want the loop to end?

Comment: Among the other errors mentioned, you are using the same `i` index for both loops. Don't do this - use two different variables (`i` and `j` are typical names used).

Comment: Seems to me that you should consult with a tutor, or one of the teacher's assistants.

Comment: There are *very* many highly proficient C programmers on this website that could write the code for you (including myself). However, that would not be a good way for you to learn. As pointed out by @user3386109, this is really something you should talk to your tutor/professor about.

Comment: However,  by way of some 'hints', I can say this: First, use the `%c` format in `printf` for character output; second, you should only be printing stuff (pairs of characters) inside the **inner** loop.

Comment: @AdrianMole My teacher is the reason I'm not so good with it, he doesn't teach well. There's tutors, but I can't really afford one which is why I came to SO but I'll keep trying to figure it out on my own. If I can't then I'll just accept the failing grade and work harder.

Comment: I'm truly sorry to hear that. But S.O. isn't really set up for interactive-style teaching/learning. There are some cases in which I would enter into a chat, to help out; however, it's way past midnight here and I'm about ready to quit for the night.

Comment: @AdrianMole I appreciate the thought tho, thank you! :)

Comment: I suggest you first try to solve the problem without nested loops. First, write a loop which prints the words "An", "As" and "At". After that works, write a second loop which prints the words "In", "Is" and "It. After that works too, then you can think about how to combine these two loops into one loop which is nested.

Comment: don't edit your question and changes the code after it has been answered

Comment: @phuclv: I think it was appropriate to update the question so that we could see the updated code. However, you are right that this should have been added to the bottom of the question instead of overwriting the original question. Also, I believe it was correct to delete the updated code after it is no longer needed.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel any updates should be added to the end. Otherwise existing answers and comments would be vandalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you want to write the first letter of `v[]` combined with each letter of `c[]`

Then write the second letter of `v[]` combined with each letter of `c[]`

This hints the first/outer loop would be stepping through the array `v[]`

This hints the second/inner loop would be stepping through the array `c[]`

This hints within the inner loop would be outputting the current letter from `v[]` followed by the current letter from `c[]` followed by a space.

remembering that `/` (divide) has a higher precedence than `<`  see [C precedence table:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm)

(remembering that `sizeof()` returns the number of characters in an object so obtaining the number of entries in an array is the total size of the array, in characters, divided by the number of characters in the first element of the array)

how to step through array `v[]`:

```
for( int i=0; i < sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]); i++ )
```

how to step though array `c[]`:

```
for( int j=0; j < sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]); j++ )
```

within the inner loop to print the current entry in `v[]` followed by the current entry in `c[]` followed by a space:

```
printf( "%c%c ", v[i], c[j] )
```

of course the above call to `printf()` places everything into the `stdout` I/O stream buffer and you actually want to display the output on the terminal, so after the nested loops exit, suggest:

printf( "\n" );

which is one way to flush the `stdout` buffer to the terminal.

Of course, all the above needs to be in a `main()` function

Of course, to use `printf()` need to include the header file: `stdio.h`

If you need clarification on any of the details, post a comment to this answer.

regarding:

```
 printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", c[6]);
```

the number of `output format conversion specifiers must match the number of values to be output.  In the current statement, 6 output specifiers does not match one value to be output.

Also, the `c[]` array only has 3 elements and C is zero based, so the only valid indexes are 0..2, not 6.  Accessing index 6 results in accessing beyond the end of the array, which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer was perfect! It taught me step by step without directly giving me the code and answer. I really appreciate it. However, there is one issue. The output I got was: AAn As At IAIn Is It.

But the output that is expected is: viz, An, As, At, In, Is, It. I'll edit my code

Comment: @mmno: "viz" is not part of the expected answer. It just means "that is to say". See [this link](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/viz) for further information.

Comment: @mmno: What is the point of the first `printf` line? You are printing the variable `j` which has (correctly) not even been initialized yet?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel These were his instructions: Print together the chars from above two arrays to print the six valid two letter words in English (viz, An, As, At, In, Is, It). So I'm assuming viz is part of it

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Ohhh I got confused. I just removed it and now it works. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @mmno: I assume that "viz," should be "viz." (period instead of comma). Then it means "that is to say" or "namely". It doesn't make sense as expected output, because it is not a two-letter word.